# Unable to execute extern c function in Unity 5

Tags: c#, c++, c, unity-game-engine, ffi

Currently i am trying to embed [CEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/) into Unity. I have managed to compile cefsimple example as dll and use it in ordinary console application by using DllImport with following code:

```
[DllImport("cefsimple")]
public static extern ulong StartCustom();
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StartCustom();
}
```

and corresponding C function:

```
extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) int StartCustom() {
    return wWinMain(nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, 0);
}
```

(All the necessary files I have moved to a folder with created .exe file)

But if i try to do the same in Unity i am getting

```
Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/cefsimple.dll' with error 'The specified procedure could not be found.

DllNotFoundException: cefsimple
Launcher.Init () (at Assets/Plugins/Launcher.cs:13)
```

Is there are any way to fix this?

Comment: `Assets/Plugins/cefsimple.dll` looks like a relative path and `DllNotFoundException` looks like the DLL itself isn't found... Can you set an absolute path just to check?

Comment: another lead: doesn't your dll has dependencies with other dlls which aren't copied in the same directory?

Comment: Thanks for quick answer.
I tried to replace the path and got the following error:
    `DllNotFoundException: C:\Users\rstoliar\Documents\CefExample\Assets\Plugins\cefsimple`.
But first error(`Failed to load 'Assets/Plugins/cefsimple.dll' with error 'The specified procedure could not be found`) is gone.

Comment: I have copied the same files as in ordinary console application.

Comment: definitely a dependency DLL issue. Try to open your DLL with dependency walker tool and see which ones are missing.

Comment: Thanks.
Here is the result I got: 
https://imgur.com/a/mxYCKFo

It looks like i have to put this dlls inside Plugins directory?

Comment: will check later, the imgur site is blocked from work ;)

Answer (score 0):

first you most define dll import and export directives in your c  application like this:

```
#ifndef YOUR_SOURCE_NAME_H //header guard
#define YOUR_SOURCE_NAME_H

    #define YOUR_SOURCE_NAME_EXPORT (1)

    #ifdef YOUR_SOURCE_NAME_EXPORT
        #define DLL_USAGE_MODE extern "C"  __declspec(dllexport)   // export DLL information
    #else
        #define DLL_USAGE_MODE  extern "C" __declspec(dllimport)   // import DLL information
    #endif


#endif // YOUR_SOURCE_NAME_H
```

you most put DLL_USAGE_MODE before your function name to make it accessable from outside.
for example you have below function in your c DLL :

```
DLL_USAGE_MODE int saySomthing(const char* pText) {
    printf("\n%s", pText);
    return 0;
}
```

now in your c# application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program {
    [DllImport("address_of_your_dll.dll", EntryPoint = "saySomthing", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    internal static extern int saySomthing(string text);

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        saySomthing("HelloWorld !!");
    }
}
```